# Do STMF411 boards have a problem with the D+ pull up resistor?

Tags: arduino, resistors, stm32, pullup

I found [this](http://amitesh-singh.github.io/stm32/2017/05/27/Overcoming-wrong-pullup-in-blue-pill.html) webpage that mentions problems with the ("blue pill") STM32F103 boards. The problem is that the value of pull up resistor on D+ is wrong. Do the ("black pill") STMF411 boards have the same issue? Seems like stock photos on eBay have the 'wrong' pull up resistor (103) instead of the correct one (1.5k).

All I want to do with these boards is upload a new firmware.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the actual problem that you are having?

Comment: I want to purchase an STM board, but was concerned whether there would be any issues with USB communication due to the pull up resistor. I have experience purchasing Arduino boards and don't seem to have any problem with those. So I was wondering if this was a prevalent issue with STM boards.

Comment: That would depend on which board with STM32F411 you mean - and you mean the Black Pill. The need for a pull-up must be in the MCU documentation, have you tried to find it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll try to do that.

Comment: Which specific board you mean? Add a link to the original post. I have not been able to find F411-based Black Pill with any pull-up on USB_DP.

Comment: Buy boards from ST not these side market, inconsistent, multiple vendor products...Or you get what you get, I usually buy blue pills by the handful because at least one of them fails...They are not high quality not in design nor production...

Comment: no reason to assume any schematic you happen to find for one of these boards matches the board you buy at some random place.

Comment: @Justme This is the post I was referring to: http://amitesh-singh.github.io/stm32/2017/05/27/Overcoming-wrong-pullup-in-blue-pill.html

Answer (score 2):

STM32F411 has OTG_FS hardware, which has internal pull-ups controlled by the software. Board designs using this uC don't need to provide external ones.

I once came across a damaged STM32F407, which somehow got its internal USB pull-up damaged. I had to provide/solder an external pull-up resistor on the board. But this is an extreme situation.